# JavaScript console.log causes error: "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated..."

Tags: jquery, debugging, firefox, backbone.js, console.log

I have been adding logs to the console to check the status of different variables without using the Firefox debugger.

However, in many places in which I add a `console.log` in my `main.js` file, I receive the following error instead of my lovely little handwritten messages to myself:

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/

What alternatives to or wrappers for `console.log` can I add to my code use that will not cause this error?

Am I "doing it wrong"?

Comment: I don't see how a console.log() call would cause an ajax call, unless there's some kind of remote logging plugin enabled or whatever.

Comment: I'm not sure it's making an ajax call. Would it help if I included a screenshot?

Comment: xmlhttprequest is an ajax request, basically.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure, either. I will include some context. I would really like to get this resolved. The International Network in all its knowledge and splendour, may it live for ever, has not produced any answer useful to my case.

Comment: `<script>$.ajaxPrefilter(function( options, originalOptions, jqXHR ) {
   options.async = true;
});</script>`   this will removes the warning. You can see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28322636/synchronous-xmlhttprequest-warning-and-script) for same issue.

Comment: I had the same error message and fixed when I corrected an another problem in my code.

Comment: I just used get instead of post, it helped. jQuery.

Comment: Beware. In my case it was not my code, but **Last Password** add-on for Google Chrome that was causing this warning.

Answer (score 304):

This happened to me when I was being lazy and included a script tag as part of the content that was being returned. As such:

Partial HTML Content:

```
<div> 
 SOME CONTENT HERE
</div>
<script src="/scripts/script.js"></script>
```

It appears, at least in my case, that if you return HTML content like that via xhr, you will cause jQuery to make a call to get that script. That call happens with an async flag false since it assumes you need the script to continue loading.

In situations like this one you'd be better served by looking into a binding framework of some kind and just returning a JSON object, or depending on your backend and templating you could change how you load your scripts.

You could also use [jQuery's `getScript()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) to grab relevant scripts. Here is a fiddle, It's just a straight copy of the jQuery example, but I'm not seeing any warnings thrown when scripts are loaded that way.

**Example**

```
<script>
var url = "/scripts/script.js";
$.getScript(url);
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/49tkL0qd/

Comment: the error is because the OP is using somewhere an synchronous XMLHttpRequests, I don't think due jquery since doesn't seems that he use it... however this is happening to me when I try to load a `<script>` as you said in an callback of an ajax asynchronous call. My ajax call is asynchronous however in the callback I make `$('#object').html(data)` where data is a piece of `html` with `<script>` and when this line is executed the error appears in the `js console`. +1!!! thanks `:)`.

Comment: For this project, I did, in fact, use JQuery.

Comment: @37coins, if this was the answer; mark it as so.. and replace javascript tag with jQuery.

Comment: This was my problem, and most likely the OP's problem too - OP please consider marking this as the answer. The higher voted answer here currently does nothing to help people with this problem, so accepting this answer would help others immensely.

Comment: just FYI jQuery getScript breaks caching.  I think .ajax will do same and allow for caching

Comment: If you are using Angular and getting the error, it happens if you put <script type="text/ng-template" id="template.html"> in your template / partial file

Comment: Please Google: link this word SOLVED ! with this OP and help people like me!!! XDXDXD (By the way, I've been searching for answers months and months and it's a pity that the question about 'console.log' avoided me to locate this before, and very embarrassing for me to discover the problem was occasioned by something as simple as that). Thx.

Comment: Wouldn't using the [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#Attributes) attribute in the script tag prevent jQuery from making a synchronous call?

Comment: @YusrilMaulidanRaji tomorrow, indeed, never came. In fact, our planet has completed one more rotation around our local star since your very own comment was added, and still no marking of this answer as the approved one.

Comment: I am getting `Uncaught TypeError: jQuery.easing[jQuery.easing.def] is not a function` after using `$.getScript(url);` as above.

Comment: @ShanikaEdiriweera You might be missing an a script tag, or import? It sounds like jQuery.easing or some part of it is not being pulled across.

Comment: I was unable to reproduce this issue using both success() and done(). Possibly only present in older versions of the library? I tested on 1.12.4.

Answer (score 81):

The warning message MAY BE due to an XMLHttpRequest request within the main thread with the async flag set to false.

https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#synchronous-flag:

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest outside of workers is in the process of
>   being removed from the web platform as it has detrimental effects to
>   the end user's experience. (This is a long process that takes many
>   years.) Developers must not pass false for the async argument when the
>   JavaScript global environment is a document environment. User agents
>   are strongly encouraged to warn about such usage in developer tools
>   and may experiment with throwing an InvalidAccessError exception when
>   it occurs.

The future direction is to only allow XMLHttpRequests in worker threads. The message is intended to be a warning to that effect.

Comment: no, the message warning is **PRESUMABLY** due to an XMLHttpRequest request within the main thread with the async flag set to false.  This  could very well be a bug in Firefox (but it's likely a jQuery feature/implementation); either way, how would describing part of the spec be considered an answer to a question that claims `console.log` is sending these warnings?

Comment: @Brett - the last two sentences of my answer explain why I included the part of the spec I did. I will edit my answer to be more precise.

Comment: with all that said, Everything you've stated in this answer is correct information; furthermore it's likely relevant to the likely problem; that is, the raising of this warning affects the behavior and/or stability of the debugger. Thus, the workaround may very well be to keep the warning from raising by correcting the cause of it.

Comment: They should add an about:flag to enable it for local debugging. Sync XHR can be very useful for tooling/debug frameworks running localhost.

Answer (score 73):

I was also facing same issue but able to fix it by putting async: true. I know it is by default true but it works when I write it explicitly

```
$.ajax({
   async: true,   // this will solve the problem
   type: "POST",
   url: "/Page/Method",
   contentType: "application/json",
   data: JSON.stringify({ ParameterName: paramValue }),
});
```

Comment: It wasn't  the reason in my case ... only removing async: false without changing to true fixed that

Comment: @Irfan in my case it was setting sync: false that helped!

Comment: to put async:true have reason to make it sync request for particular case. So removing it not a solution.

Comment: in my case async: true, solved the warning

Answer (score 42):

Visual Studio 2015/2017's live debugger is injecting code that contains the deprecated call.

Comment: I spent quite some time trying to figure out why I was seeing this warning; I figured I would share on the most appropriate SO question so others could save some time.

Comment: So very helpful. Thank-you. One can spend hours looking for the cause, as I have, thinking that it's one's own error in code somewhere when the cause is somewhere else entirely.

Comment: Thank you, so can you tell me how to solve this warning?

Comment: Once the debugger is detached, it won't get injected and wont be a problem

Answer (score 23):

Sometimes it's necessary to ajax load a script but delay *document ready* until after the script is loaded.

jQuery supports this with the `holdReady()` function.

**Example usage:**

```
$.holdReady(true);                              //set hold
function releaseHold() { $.holdReady(false); }  //callback to release hold
$.getScript('script.js', releaseHold);          //load script then release hold
```

The actual script loading is asynchronous (**no error**), but the effect is synchronous if the rest of your JavaScript runs after *document ready*.

> This *advanced feature* would typically be used by dynamic script
>   loaders that want to load additional JavaScript such as jQuery plugins
>   before allowing the ready event to occur, even though the DOM may be
>   ready.

Documentation:
     https://api.jquery.com/jquery.holdready

---

#### UPDATE January 7, 2019

From [JQMIGRATE](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/blob/master/warnings.md#jqmigrate-jqueryholdready-is-deprecated):

> **jQuery.holdReady() is deprecated**
>
> **Cause:** The `jQuery.holdReady()` method has been deprecated due to its detrimental effect on the global performance of the page. This method can prevent all the code on the page from initializing for extended lengths of time.
>
> **Solution:** Rewrite the page so that it does not require all jQuery ready handlers to be delayed. This might be accomplished, for example, by late-loading only the code that requires the delay when it is safe to run. Due to the complexity of this method, jQuery Migrate does not attempt to fill the functionality. If the underlying version of jQuery used with jQuery Migrate no longer contains `jQuery.holdReady()` the code will fail shortly after this warning appears.

Answer (score 20):

To avoid this warning, do not use:

```
async: false
```

in any of your $.ajax() calls. This is the only feature of XMLHttpRequest that's deprecated.

The default is

```
async: true
```

[jQuery has deprecated synchronous XMLHTTPRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27736186/jquery-has-deprecated-synchronous-xmlhttprequest/27736383#27736383)

Answer (score 13):

@Webgr partial answer actually helped me debug this warning @ console log, shame the other part of that answer brought so many downvotes :(

Anyway, here is how I found out what was the cause of this warning in my case:

1. Use Chrome Browser > Hit F12 to bring DevTools
2. Open the **drawer menu** (in Chrome 3 vertical dots in the upper right)
3. Under **Console** > check **Log XMLHttpRequests** option
4. Reload your page that was giving you the error and observe what happens on each ajax request in the console log.

In my case, another plugin was loading 2 **.js libraries** after each ajax call, that were absolutely not required nor necessary. Disabling the rogue plugin removed the warning from the log. From that point, you can either try to fix the problem yourself (e.g. limit the loading of the scripts to certain pages or events - this is way too specific for an answer here) or contact 3rd party plugin developer to solve it.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: // , Thanks for the answer! This question only referred to Firefox. I'm interested to see that it occurred on Chrome. This only seems to remove the warning, rather than actually fixing the problem, though. Is that correct?

Comment: It seems that Chrome has more advanced stuff in the DevTools than Firefox version. The fact that it is not reported in Firefox does not mean it is not present. This completely fixed my problem, not just hidden it. I have removed the scripts from the problematic plugin and page that were 'reloaded' on each ajax call.

Comment: // , Do you think it is worth raising an issue with the Firefox developers?

Comment: No, not necessary. I have just re-tested my case with latest Firefox and "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread..." warning was definitely reported in the console log, as well. So, it was, at least in my case, not a browser specific issue. Now, how you can use Firefox to debug XMLHttpRequest via Network tab, by watching the .js resources being called after each ajax request. Does the same thing, although it is more streamlined/filtered in Chrome.


https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor

Answer (score 8):

I have been looking at the answers all impressive. I think He should provide the code that is giving him a problem. Given the example below, If you have a script to link to jquery in page.php then you get that notice.

```
$().ready(function () {
    $.ajax({url: "page.php",
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (result) {
        $("#page").html(result);
   }});
 });
```

Answer (score 7):

I get such warning in following case:

1) file1 which contains `<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>`. Page has input fields. I enter some value in input field and click button. Jquery sends input to external php file.

2) external php file also contains jquery and in the external php file i also included `<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>`. Because if this i got the warning.

Removed `<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>` from external php file and works without the warning.

As i understand on loading the first file (file1), i load `jquery-1.10.2.js` and as the page does not reloads (it sends data to external php file using jquery `$.post`), then `jquery-1.10.2.js` continue to exist. So not necessary again to load it.

Answer (score 6):

This is solved in my case.

> JS

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function( options, original_Options, jqXHR ) {
    options.async = true;
});
```

This answer was inserted in this link

[**https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28322636/synchronous-xmlhttprequest-warning-and-script**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28322636/synchronous-xmlhttprequest-warning-and-script)

Answer (score 5):

I got this exception when I set url in query like "example.com/files/text.txt". Ive changed url to "http://example.com/files/text.txt" and this exception dissapeared.

Comment: My issue also seems to have to do with the URL.  I copied a script to a temporary URL to work on it, and that is when the error showed up.  Not from the original URL.

Answer (score 5):

And I got this exception for including one can.js script inside another, e.g.,

```
{{>anotherScript}}
```

Comment: This seems to be the main cause (loading additional <scripts> and appending them to the <head> in the DOM)

Answer (score 5):

In a MVC application, I got this warning because I was opening a Kendo Window with a method that was returning a View(), instead of a PartialView(). The View() was trying to retrive again all the scripts of the page.

Answer (score 5):

It was happening to me in ZF2.
I was trying to load the Modal content but I forgot to disable the layout before.

So:

```
$viewModel = new ViewModel();
$viewModel->setTerminal(true);
return $viewModel;
```

Answer (score 5):

Like @Nycen I also got this error because of a link to Cloudfare.  Mine was for the **Select2** plugin.

to fix it I just removed

```
 src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.min.js"
```

and the error went away.

Answer (score 5):

1. In Chrome, `press F12`
2. Develomping tools-> press `F1`.
3. See settings->general->Apperance: `"Don't show chrome Data Saver warning"`- set this checkbox.
4. See settings->general->Console: `"Log XMLHTTPRequest"` - set this checkbox too.

Enjoy

Answer (score 4):

In my case this was caused by the **flexie** script which was part of the "CDNJS Selections" app offered by **Cloudflare**.

According to Cloudflare "This app is being deprecated in March 2015". I turned it off and the message disappeared instantly.

You can access the apps by visiting https://www.cloudflare.com/a/cloudflare-apps/yourdomain.com

NB: this is a copy of my answer on this thread [Synchronous XMLHttpRequest warning and <script>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28322636/synchronous-xmlhttprequest-warning-and-script/30332136#30332136) (I visited both when looking for a solution)

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this with below steps:

1. Check your CDN scripts and add them locally.
2. Move your scripts includes into the header section.

Answer (score 3):

In my particular case I was rendering a Rails partial without `render layout: false` which was re-rendering the entire layout, including all of the scripts in the `<head>` tag.  Adding `render layout: false` to the controller action fixed the problem.

Answer (score 3):

For me, the problem was that in an OK request, I expected the ajax response to be a well formatted HTML string such as a table, but in this case, the server was experiencing a problem with the request, redirecting to an error page, and was therefore returning back the HTML code of the error page (which had a `<script` tag somewhere. I console logged the ajax response and that's when I realized it was not what I was expecting, then proceeded to do my debugging.

Answer (score 3):

The question raised in 2014 and it's 2019 so I guess it's good to look for better option.

You can simply use `fetch` api in Javascript which provide you more flexibility.

for example, see this code

```
fetch('./api/some.json')
    .then((response) => {
        response.json().then((data) => { 
            ... 
        });
    })
    .catch((err) => { ... });
```

Comment: is this pure js, no plugin require?

Comment: @Alok Yes, Please look at this https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch

Comment: // , Do you really consider this a viable alternative to `console.log()`?

Comment: @NathanBasanese Sorry I didn't get your question, you means // for console.log ? or fetch or XMLHttpRequest?.

Answer (score -1):

I found these problem cause early redirect page before javascript finish, in my case firebase rtdb set function.