# why angularjs website cannot show ng-view content in firefox?

Tags: angularjs, ajax, firefox

I am working on a angularjs website and when I Upload my site to public server
it work fine if i open this site by Chrome but in firefox only index content show to user and route change donot add template to ng-view?
there is no error or warning in console only this:

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience

Comment: Can you provide your HTML code (where you use ng-view) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript console.log causes error: "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated..."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24639335/javascript-console-log-causes-error-synchronous-xmlhttprequest-on-the-main-thr)

Answer (score 0):

I found very silly bug in fire fox witch add a 'height:0px' to my view class and it make my ng-view invisible ....

I add 'height:auto !important;' style to it to show my content on ng-view .