# jQuery not working in MVC partialview after moving the JavaScript code to separate file and reference the file in a script tag cause problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

I am new to web development and I am using .net core MVC with VS2017, and trying to load several partial views inside a div (section1 and section2) using ajax and javascript.

My index page:

```html
<div>
    <a asp-action="setupprogram"  asp-controller="Setup" data-target="Section1" class="section1">Setup Programs</a>  
</div>
<br />
<div id="Section1"></div>
<br />
<div id="Section2"></div>
<br />
```

When I include the javascript code inside the chtml it run perfectly, but when I remove the jQuery code and put it inside `site.js`, it didn't work

My site.js code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#Sform").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var urlsx = $('#UrlsX').val();
        var urls = $('#Urls').val();
      
        $.ajax({
            url: urls,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "html",
            data: $('#Sform').serialize(),
            success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                $('#Section2').html(data);
                $("#Section1").load(urlsx)
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $("#Section2").html(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    });

    $('.section1').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#Section1").show();
        $('#' + $(this).data("target")).load($(this).attr("href"));
    });

    $('.section2').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#Section1").show();
        $("#Section2").show();
        $('#' + $(this).data("target")).load($(this).attr("href"));
    });

  
});
```

the simple way to solve this issue is to include the script tag

```
<script src="~/js/site.js"></script>
```

at each partial view to load the JavaScript code after the DOM load and to be able to find the required objects, accounting to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-to-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-the/9899701#9899701) and also this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24639335/javascript-console-log-causes-error-synchronous-xmlhttprequest-on-the-main-thr)

Mmy problem is that the JavaScript code make the page load time too long after few clicks and it themes that the code is looping inside my C# action several times and making the page load time unaccepted.

Also the second partial view do not recognize the code and load in a new page rather than being rendered in the Section2 div.

The `site.js` file is referanced in the `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
 <environment names="Development">
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js"></script>@*asp-append-version="true"*@
</environment>
```

The first patial view that load in section one is as follwoing :

```html
@foreach (var p in Model)
{
    <div>
        @p.ProgName

            <a asp-action="setupprogramEdit" asp-controller="Setup" asp-route-id="@p.ProgID" data-target="Section2" class="section2">Edit</a>
            || <a asp-action="setupprogramdelete" asp-controller="Setup" asp-route-id="@p.ProgID" data-target="Section2" class="section2">Delete</a>
    </div>
}
<div>
    <a asp-action="setupprogram" asp-controller="Setup" data-target="Section1" class="cancel2">cancel</a> 
</div>
```

- First : is it better to keep the JavaScript code inside the chtml view page ?\
- Second : any idea how to come over this issue, in case i decided to move the JavaScript code into a separate file ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Is best to keep the jquery code in a separate file and include that file in your view.
2. If your page loading time is big, why you don't load the partials when you click the button instead of loading them all at once and keeping them hidden?

Also you are requesting the same partials multiple times?

Comment: then - how to prevent the action and JS to be called increment times with each click, I mean that when i include the JavaScript file in the partial view, my action is called first click Twice (because the file is referenced two times) and second click the action is called four times and so on ....

Comment: You include the js in your main view not in partial. Also put it in a different file, not site.js and reference that file.