# jQuery returning deprecated error on server online, localhost OK

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest

My script uses jQuery 3.3.1 to request a login page, and is returning an error instead of logged in or out, on the server PHP is 5.6 with Apache / Linux, and the local server where it works is the same version it works.

```
<form class="js-validate" id="formLogin" name="formLogin" autocomplete="off" accept-charset="UTF-8" onSubmit="return false;">

  <div class="row">                 
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 mb-6">
      <div class="js-form-message">
        <label for="user_email" class="h5 d-block text-uppercase">Email address</label>
        <div class="js-focus-state input-group u-form">
          <input type="email" autocomplete="false" class="form-control u-form__input" id="user_email" name="user_email" required placeholder="email@example.com" aria-label="email@example.com" data-msg="Please enter a valid email address." data-error-class="u-has-error" data-success-class="u-has-success">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 mb-6">
      <div class="js-form-message">
        <label for="user_password" class="h5 d-block text-uppercase">Password</label>
        <div class="js-focus-state input-group u-form">
          <input type="password" autocomplete="false" class="form-control u-form__input" id="user_password" name="user_password" required placeholder="********" aria-label="********" data-msg="Your password is invalid, please try again." data-error-class="u-has-error" data-success-class="u-has-success">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>                      
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      <div id="returnResponse"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 text-left">
      <a class="font-size-14 font-weight-bold title-green" href="login/recuperar-senha/">I forgot my password!</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 text-right">
      <button id="btnSend" type="submit" class="btn btnp-success btn-sm color-1 material-design transition-3d-hover" data-color="#004740">Sign in</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<!-- SCRIPT - LOGIN -->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#formLogin").on('submit', function(){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url: "login/send-form/",
                data: $('#formLogin').serialize(),
                beforeSend: function(){
                    $('#btnSend').attr("disabled","disabled");
                    $('#formLogin').css("opacity",".5");
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#formLogin')[0].reset();
                    $('#returnResponse').html(data);
                    $('#formLogin').css("opacity","");
                    $("#btnSend").removeAttr("disabled");
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

On the console it returns an error and does not execute the request, on localhost it works:

> [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is
>   deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's
>   experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/24639335/5573206

Comment: Not duplicated, this reality is other.

Answer (score 0):

As of reading the referred link in comment which mention following

**"Synchronous XMLHttpRequest outside of workers is in the process of being removed from the web platform as it has detrimental effects to the end user’s experience. (This is a long process that takes many years.) Developers must not pass false for the async argument when current global object is a Window object. User agents are strongly encouraged to warn about such usage in developer tools and may experiment with throwing an "InvalidAccessError" DOMException when it occurs."**

I think some how your ajax request is synchronous which should be async by default in 
jquery Ajax, so try to add `async: true` in your ajax request .