# While calling ajax getting " [Deprecation] " on my browser console

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am making an ajax call and it is implementing successfully and loading my data. On my browser console I am getting `Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user’s experience. For more help http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/`

**Code**

```
$("#formIdoutletwisetable").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); 
      $.ajax({
            async: true,
            url : "DateWiseOlWiseSales",
            method : "POST",

            data : {
                   Outlet : currentlyClickedOutlet,                         
                 },                          
        });   
        $.ajax({
             async: true,
            url : "NoData",
            method : "GET",
            dataType : "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data : {
                   fromdate : $("#startdate").val(),               
                 },         
            success : function(data) {
            // console.log("firstdata",data.length);
                if(data.length>1)
                    {                       
                    $.ajax({
                         async: true,
                        url : "DateWiseOlWiseSales",
                        method : "GET",
                        dataType : "json",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        data : {
                               fromdate : $("#startdate").val(),
                             },                              
                        success : function(data) {                                                          
                // console.log("tst",data);
                             $("#formIdoutletwisetable").hide();
                                let formatedData = formatData(data);
                                renderTable(formatedData);          
                        }        
                    });                     
                    }                   
                else
                    {
                    alert('No data found between dates');
                    window.location = 'Somelocation.html';
                    }
                    }                                                                                
        });
```

});

i have added the full code of my one of report that makes the ajax call.

Am I doing anything wrong even if I don't have great knowledge about `[Deprecation]`? Is it harmful for my application?

[image: console i mage]

i am using unminified jquery and after that on clicking on the link on right of console i am getting this as shown in image

Comment: As mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24639335/javascript-console-log-causes-error-synchronous-xmlhttprequest-on-the-main-thr  add `   async: true` in your ajax request.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript console.log causes error: "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24639335/javascript-console-log-causes-error-synchronous-xmlhttprequest-on-the-main-thr)

Comment: @VasylMoskalov i have done that but getting same error on my browser console

Comment: Could you check is this request produces warning?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186091/discussion-between-dheeraj-kumar-and-vasyl-moskalov).

Answer (score -1):

Did you included a script tag as part of the content that was being returned. Like :

```
<html> 
 <head></head>
<body></body>
</html>
<script src="script path"></script>
```

You can use jQuery's getScript() to get scripts content instead of used like above code. please find below sample code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var script_path = "js script path";
$.getScript(script_path);
</script>
```

Also you can check here [You can check example here](http://jsfiddle.net/49tkL0qd/)

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with the above question? Did you intend to post this as an answer to another question?

Comment: yupp this is from the post you guyz have suggested me

Comment: Actually when we get the html content through ajax call and included js scripts   in that html we have get deprecation errors in console so to resolved that we just have to use jquery function $.getScript(script_path);