# How can we send a HTTP request synchronously?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

If I am correct, "A" in "AJAX" means sending a HTTP request asynchronously without waiting for a HTTP response.

I learn that we can send an asynchronous HTTP request by `XMLHttpRequest`, for example:

```
function handleButtonPress(e) { 
    var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = handleResponse; 
    httpRequest.open("GET", e.target.innerHTML +  ".html"); 
    httpRequest.send(); 
}
```

How can we send a HTTP request synchronously?

Comment: What use case do you have for synchronous requests? In general they are not recommended (certain browsers even state this in their console when a synchronous request is sent)

Comment: Just put `false` as the 3rd parameter to open, but a big warning, if you use this feature not inside a WebWorker it might stop working in the future.

Comment: I suppose the question is more about alternatives to XMLHttpRequest, no?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript console.log causes error: "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24639335/javascript-console-log-causes-error-synchronous-xmlhttprequest-on-the-main-thr)

Comment: @Keith Thanks. where do you recommend to look up the API usages?

Comment: @Tim MDN usually has good docs on stuff like this ->  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/open

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The third param in open function is for async request sending.
You can set it to false for a synchronous request

```
function handleButtonPress(e) { 
    var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = handleResponse; 
    httpRequest.open("GET", e.target.innerHTML +  ".html", false); 
    httpRequest.send(); 
}
```