# "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated" error after authentication and redirect in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm working on a react application wherein a user can register, and upon registering, the user would then be redirected to the home page.

Below is how I currently have my code.

The problem is after the user submits the registration form and the registration is successful, once the user is redirected I get the following warning message in the browser console:

```
[Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
```

I tried two ways of redirecting, using `history.push` (passed as a prop from the `Route` component), and using the `Redirect` component once I update the state and `RegisterForm` is rerendered. The warning message is displayed regardless of which method I use.

My question is what am I doing wrong, and how do I fix this problem?

I've seen a lot of other questions regarding this issue, but they mostly just describe why this warning is getting displayed, but not necessarily how to fix the issue causing the warning.

```
class RegisterForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            loggedIn: false,
            username: '',
            email: '',
            password: '',
            passwordConfirmation: ''
        };

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        const target = event.target;
        const name = target.name;
        const value = target.value;

        this.setState({
            [name]: value
        });
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        axios.post('/users/register', {
            email: this.state.email,
            username: this.state.username,
            password: this.state.password,
            password_confirmation: this.state.passwordConfirmation,
        })
        .then(response => {
            // const history = this.props.history;
            // history.push('/');

            this.setState({
                loggedIn: response.data.authenticated
            });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('Error registering user.');
        });

        event.preventDefault();
    }

    render() {
        const loggedIn = this.state.loggedIn;

        if (loggedIn) {
            return <Redirect push to="/" />
        }

        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <div>
                    <label htmlFor="email">Email:</label>
                    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                </div>

                <div>
                    <label htmlFor="username">Username:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" minLength="3" maxLength="31" value={this.state.username} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                </div>

                <div>
                    <label htmlFor="password">Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" minLength="6" value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                </div>

                <div>
                    <label htmlFor="passwordConfirmation">Confirm Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" id="passwordConfirmation" name="passwordConfirmation" minLength="6" value={this.state.passwordConfirmation} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                </div>

                <button type="submit">Register</button>
            </form>
        );
    }
}

function Register(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Register</h1>
            <RegisterForm history={props.history} />
        </div>
    );
}

function App() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Router>
                <Header />

                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
                    <Route path="/" component={Home} />
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: Axios cannot make synchronous requests afaik, but the warning is about such a request. Do you have any code still using xmlhttprequest directly? Or is your version of react or other components like years old? My react knowledge is very limited, but I cannot identify the lines in the code shown that would make a synchronous request.

Comment: @Shilly I'm using the latest version of everything. My `Home` component was loading some data from the backend, but it's also using axios, and I commented out that code to make sure it wasn't the cause for the warning message, which it wasn't.

Comment: Can you indentify which request for which file it is in the dev tools? https://stackoverflow.com/a/42058621/3049127 Apparently a lot of libraries that want to be compatible still use synchronous requests to be able to support old browsers.

Comment: @Shilly I feel dumb for not checking that sooner. It was a browser extension causing the error...