# Uncaught ReferenceError: Modernizr is not defined at HTMLDocument In Google Console

Tags: javascript, html, google-search-console

Uncaught ReferenceError: Modernizr is not defined at HTML Document In Google Console. Also facing 1 more issue with javascript console message.

```
Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of 
its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js:4
```

Comment: Please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24639335/javascript-console-log-causes-error-synchronous-xmlhttprequest-on-the-main-thr 

It may help

Comment: @SifatHaque this is too not helping